# Defer render of column value

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to show a value of another store in a column of a grid, but the store could be loaded after the grid is displayed cause if its size. I want something like this:

```
renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, gridStore, view) {
    var store = Ext.getStore('someBigStore');
    if (store.getCount() > 0) {
         return store.getById(value).get('name'); // If store is already loaded show value immediately
    } else {
        store.on('load', function(){
            var displayValue = store.getById(value).get('name');
            // -> how to insert the displayValue into the right place of the grid ?
        });
        return 'loading...' // show waiting message
    }
}
```

How can I archive this?

Comment: You can't really. The best thing to do is refresh the grid once the store loads.

Comment: It might work, but it's not a good solution. You should use the API methods rather than trawling through the DOM.

Comment: yes, but if there are no API methods for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I got it, there is no function in the framework to do this, but with a little DOM browsing:

```
store.on('load', function () {
    var row = Ext.fly(view.getNode(rowIndex));
    var cell = row.down('td:nth-child(' + (colIndex + 1) + ') .x-grid-cell-inner');
    cell.setHTML(getDisplayValue());
}, null, { single: true });
```